# Secrets management across environments in HashiCorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Problem - there are Vault instances in dev/stage/production (each independent). Now if I need to create/modify a key/value (kv secrets engine) then I can manually do so in each env. This leads to environments being out of sync and as part of the deployment we need to remember to write values to vault (I'm sure you can guess what happens).

What I would like to be able to do is externalize the paths/keys so they can applied to each environment. This could potentially be a file in Git and we just write the file through script in each env but then how do we get the values to use? Further these values are different in each environment and they need a secure location to live.

I have tried to search for this and while there is plenty about managing Vault itself I have not found any solution to managing the *data* within Vault. Any guidance would be much appreciated.